# PHP Header failed to return control to directed Page Show source code all include files and html file and php file when using header

Tags: php, header

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection/connection.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$qry = "SELECT id, email, password FROM signup WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$password."'";
$res = $con->query($qry);
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if($num_row==1)
{
$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['id'];
header('Location: index.php');
}
else
{
echo 'Incorrect Email And Password';
}
```

This is the PHP file after succesfull login I want to send to home page.
There is one html form file I send data to this php file using jquery everything working fine except header. I provide print screen image kindly have a look

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the question is, the `header(Location:);` shouldn't mess with the content of the page, since it's just a redirect.

Comment: Actually after submiting a form i just want to redirect to home page instead of redirecting it shows me home page source code and all files included on the hom page there source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($num_row==1)
{

$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['id'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location.href="index.php";
</script>
<?php

} ?>
```

Try using this..